# React native top menu of the top screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigator

I'm writing an application on react native and I want a user settings menu that will go to the top of the screen. I have attached an approximate version I want to get.

I looked at the whole Internet and didn't find a single reference where someone faced a similar problem.

[image: 1]

Comment: can't find your attachment?

Comment: sorry, attached

Comment: You're looking for a sticky header with a height animation. You might have to glue those concepts together, but you'll be able to find tutorials for them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom header just like in the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#header

En then you could use an animation library to create the animation

example structure:

```js
<View style={[props.style].flat()}>
  <View>{/* Left */}</View>

  <View style={styles.header}>
    {/* Right */}
    <Pressable onPress={onHamburgerMenuPress}>
      <HamburgerMenuSvg />
    </Pressable>
  </View>
  <animated.View style={[springProps, styles.drawer]} onLayout={onLayout}>
    {/* Drawer */}
    <Pressable onPress={closeMenuPress} style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end" }}>
      <XSvg />
    </Pressable>
    <View>
      <MenuButton Icon={LogOutSvg} onPress={onLogout}>
        <Text light>Log out</Text>
      </MenuButton>
    </View>
  </animated.View>
</View>;
```

and then you could have something like:

```js
  const springProps = useSpring({
    top: hideMenu && layout ? -layout.height : 0,
    pointerEvents: hideMenu ? 'none' : 'auto',
    config: {
      easing: easings.easeInOutCirc,
      duration: 200,
    },
  });
```

This should give you an idea on how to create that type of navigation.